# django many to many through

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a coaching system and I'm a little lost about serialization in django.I have a many to many through model to control the appointments and I want to get all data about the coach/coachee involved in the relationship.

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    """docstring for Appointment"""
    coach = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='coaches', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coachee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='coachees', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schedule_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    due_date = models.DateField()
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

Using the following serializer I can get the primary keys involved but I'd really like to get the coach and coachee details in one request.

```
#return appointment data
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """docstring for AppointmentSerializer"""
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('id', 'schedule_date', 'due_date', 'coach', 'coachee', 'summary', 'condition')
```

Comment: Wow this was fast and very usefull. I used the depth=1 option and it worked! thank you very much. As a newbie I really appreciate everyone's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `depth` option on the `Meta` class.

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """docstring for AppointmentSerializer"""
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('id', 'schedule_date', 'due_date', 'coach', 'coachee', 'summary', 'condition')
        depth = 1
```

This will generate nested representations.

Alternatively, you can explicitly specify serializers if you need more control.

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    coach = CoachSerializer()
    coachee = CoacheeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('id', 'schedule_date', 'due_date', 'coach', 'coachee', 'summary', 'condition')
```

You can also add single fields from your related models:

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """docstring for AppointmentSerializer"""
    coach_name = serializers.CharField(source='coach.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('id', 'schedule_date', 'due_date', 'coach', 'coachee', 'summary', 'condition')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. The common one is create serializer for user and use it instead of defaults fields:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ...

class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coach = UserSerializer()
    coachee = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('id', 'schedule_date', 'due_date', 'coach', 'coachee', 'summary', 'condition')
```

But there will be a problem if you want to use `AppointmentSerializer` for creating an instance. You will not be able to pass an id's of users to that fields. In that case you could use default fields and override `to_representation` method.

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('id', 'schedule_date', 'due_date', 'coach', 'coachee', 'summary', 'condition')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(AppointmentSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['coach'] = UserSerializer(instance.coach).data
        representation['coachee'] = UserSerializer(instance.coachee).data
        return representation
```